# MongoDB putting they key into $set instead of using it for lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a message using userID as my _id

Is splitting it up into findOne - Save - Update the best way?

```
//
// Find and update message
//
var messageModel = require('../models/messageModel');
var messageTable = mongoose.model('messageModel');
var messageRecord = new messageModel();
var findMessage = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("=====START findMessage=====")
    messageTable.findOne(
        { _id: userID }                            
    ,function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(new Error('findMessage: ' + err))
            return;
        }

        // Who will have this as unread?
        if (userManager==true) {
            messageRecord.readUser = false;
            messageRecord.readManager = true;
        } else {
            messageRecord.readUser = true;
            messageRecord.readManager = false;
        }

        // If message not found, then create new one
        if (!data) {
            console.log("=====CREATE NEW RECORD=====")
            messageRecord._id = userID;
            messageRecord.activityDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
            messageRecord.messages = {
                "message" : message, 
                "date" : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000), 
                "property" : propertyID,
                "booking" : bookingID,
                "manager" : userManager 
            }
            messageRecord.save(function (err, res) {  
                if (err) {
                    reject(new Error('findMessage: ' + err));
                    return;
                }
            })
            console.log("=====RESOLVE findMessage=====")
            resolve();
            return;
        }

        // If message found, then add message
        console.log("=====ADD LINE TO RECORD=====")
        messageTable.update (
            { _id: userID },
            { 
                $set:   { 
                            activityDate : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000),
                            readUser : messageRecord.readUser,
                            readManager : messageRecord.readManager
                        },
                $push:  { 
                    messages: {
                        "message" : message, 
                        "date" : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000), 
                        "property" : propertyID,
                        "booking" : bookingID,
                        "manager" : userManager 
                    }
                } 
            },
            { upsert: true }                         
        ).exec(function (err, res) {  
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('findMessage: ' + err));
                return;
            }
        })
        console.log("=====RESOLVE findMessage=====")
        resolve();
        return;
    });
})};
```

Do I need to put upsert:true? (what ever that means)

Or should I use findOneAndUpdate?

And would you use findOneAndUpdate or just update? And why?

I tought it went like this:

```
findone
if not found then save
if found then update
```

**UPDATE - Thanks to lascot I ended up doing this, and it works great!**

```
// Save message
messageTable.update (
    { _id: userID },
    { 
        $setOnInsert: {
            _id: userID
        },
        $set: { 
            activityDate : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000),
            readUser : messageRecord.readUser,
            readManager : messageRecord.readManager
        },
        $push:  { 
            messages: {
                "message" : message, 
                "date" : Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000), 
                "property" : propertyID,
                "booking" : bookingID,
                "manager" : userManager 
            }
        } 
    },
    { upsert: true }                         
).exec(function (err, res) {  
    if (err) {
        reject(new Error('findMessage: ' + err));
        return;
    }
})
```

Comment: `update(condition, {$set: {}, $push: {}, etc.. }, {upsert: true})` will update the documents matching your condition or create them if none are found. That's what `upsert` means

Comment: Ouuuu ok!!!  So if I only want to update if found, then I should use `findOneAndUpdate` ?  and would I also need `upsert: true` for that one?

Comment: upsert will only update if found.. if not found it will create.. isn't that what you described in your last block: findone -> if not found then save -> if found then update ?

Comment: ok, thanks @lascort - Im still not clear about "create if none are found".  If my code reaches the update statement, I do not want it to create if not found, I would want it to return an error.

Comment: then its a regular update.. what's that bit about "if not found then save about" in that case? (although it will not return an error)

Comment: @lascort hmmm after I added the `upsert:true`  , then I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined` - Im not sure if this is because of some error in the statement or am I missing an error handler?

Comment: Found it - `messageRecord = new messageModel();` that wont work unless you do `.save`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147756/discussion-between-torbenrudgaard-and-lascort).